# RESTful API access sub-resource by type or id

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I have some resources with 2 types of sub-resources.
Each resource has its unique id. And **I'd like to support accessing by id**.

What I am doing currently is:

- List sub-resources by type

  - `GET /resources/type_1_subs`
  - `GET /resources/type_2_subs`
- List all sub-resources

  - `GET /resources`
- Create sub-resource

  - `POST /resources/type_1_subs`
  - `POST /resources/type_2_subs`

I use separate `POST`, because **input json schemas are different for 2 types**.

To access resource by id, I think this is the natural way:

- `GET /resources/:id`

But this looks strange, becuase the same part of uri has different meanings.

I think an alternative way is to access sub-resources with type as parameter.

- List sub-resources by type

  - `GET /resources?type=1`
  - `GET /resources?type=2`
- List all sub-resources

  - `GET /resources`
- Get sub-resource by id

  - `GET /resources/:id`

For retrieving, this looks natural.

But for sub-resource creation, I am not sure what is the best practice.

1. Use resource type as parameter, and input json unchanged.

   - `POST /resources?type=1`
   - `POST /resources?type=2`
2. Put type to the input json

   - `POST /resources`
   - `{ "type": 1 or 2, TYPE_DEPENDENCY_FIELDS}`

     I am not comfortable with this, because the json schema is not strict.

Any recommendation on the best practice on this scenario?

Comment: There's no real 'subresources' here, just 'resources'.

Comment: @Evert It means to retrieve a subset of 'resources' I should use `GET /resources?type=SOMETYPE`; to create new resource of some type, I should `POST /resources` with json for that type. Is my interpretation right?

Comment: Right, most people wouldn't call a subset of resources, subresources. They are kinda different.